# SQL Query - list of files by longest loading time

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to filter a db table by file loading time.

This is what i have now:

```
SELECT url, timings_wait, SUM( timings_wait ) 
FROM request_detail
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY SUM( timings_wait ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The query selectes all the files, sums for each file the loading time and orders the list by the total loading time per file;

Please help to get the list ordered by the longest time per file, not total loading time

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: use DISTINCT if you want unique values returned

Comment: you should probably use `MAX`: `ORDER BY MAX( timings_wait ) DESC` instead of `ORDER BY SUM( timings_wait ) DESC`. Also, I don't think you can have `timings_wait` in the `SELECT`. It should probably be `SUM` or 'MAX' instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT url, timings_wait, SUM( timings_wait ) AS s, MAX( timings_wait ) AS m
FROM request_detail
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY MAX( timings_wait ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT url, timings_wait, SUM( timings_wait ) 
FROM request_detail
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY timings_wait DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```